# Hiragana phonetic fusions in Japanese - 学校 example

Tags: pronunciation, nouns, phonetics, gemination

The word 学校 has two kanji, 学 and 校 that respectively are read がく and こう.
Does this "hiragana fusion" bewteen the last く and the first こ, have a name? I know it occurs in many many other words (like 発表, 出発, 結婚), but does it have a name, like the 連濁?

Comment: FYI: https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/159.html

Comment: Does this help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61816/9831